# GTK+ website is not openning

Tags: gtk

Official [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org) website is not opening. I tried from two computers with different connections, AIRCEL and BSNL both.
But the result I am always getting :-
Connection refused: www.gtk.org:80.

If you can open this page please report and suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.isup.me/www.gtk.org shows it's down for everyone. Nothing to do with Ubuntu AFAICT.

Comment: I tried isup.me/www.gtk.org but not opening. 

It's not just you! http://www.gtk.org looks down from here. 

Check another site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website is just down, try again in a few minutes

Comment: I'm trying this from yesterday, from Win7 to UBUNTU. I'm not sure why this is happening. I wonder whether GTK is running their server maintenance without informing others.

Comment: I think there moving from webhost or something among those lines (there offline for a few days now). If you need urgent information use http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tiTUpEmjSOwJ:www.gtk.org/+&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl to view the cached site

Comment: Thanks, I visited their temporary site. For the official site we may have to wait a fews weeks, but for the time being we can use this temp website.